# How to set spinner popup background color dynamically with hex code?

Tags: java, android, colors, background, spinner

When I try to set spinner popup background, following code works;

`setPopupBackgroundResource(R.drawable.black);`

But I need to set hex code dynamically as popup background and uses following code.But it doesn't work for me

`spinner.setPopupBackgroundResource(#FF5733)`

Thanks in advance...:)

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `setPopupBackgroundDrawable()` like this:

```
spinner.setPopupBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(0xFF5733));
```